# Getting item names from enums with multiple zero values

Tags: c#, .net, string, enums, formatting

I'm having difficulties working with some legacy enums that have multiple zero values. Whenever I call `ToString` on one of the non-zero values, all but the first zero value is included.

Is there any way to isolate the non-zero value name without resorting to string manipulation or reflection?

```
//all of the following output "Nada, Zilch, One"
Console.WriteLine(TestEnum.One);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(TestEnum.One));
Console.WriteLine(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TestEnum))
                      .ConvertToString(TestEnum.One));

[Flags]
enum TestEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    Nada = 0,
    Zilch = 0,
    One = 1
}
```

**Edit**

I understand that having multiple items with the same value is not recommended however the enum in question is defined in a legacy assembly that I can't change. In fact, there are 12 public enums in mscorlib v4 that break this recommendation, as determined by the following simple LINQ query:

```
var types = typeof (void).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsEnum &&
                   type.IsPublic &&
                   Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>()
                       .GroupBy(value => value)
                       .Any(grp => grp.Count() > 1))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's common practice to only have a single zero value. In fact it's common practice to not have any repeated values. It's an enum and there is inherent danger relying upon the 'backing' value.

Comment: Can you show some of the code how these flags are used?  Are they used as bit-masks?

Comment: Since this is quite obviously unwanted behaviour, you might want to file a bug report on this: http://connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option.  It works, but it's a bit ugly.  The values / names variables won't change, so they only need to be calculated once.

Assuming you have a slightly more complicated enum, such as:

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    Nada = 0,
    Zilch = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4
}
```

Here is some code you could use:

```
var input = TestEnum.One | TestEnum.Two;
var values = (TestEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof (TestEnum));
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (TestEnum));
var result = values
    .Select((value, index) =>
            input == value || (value != 0 && (input & value) == value)
                ? names[index]
                : null)
    .Where(name => name != null);
var text = string.Join(", ", result);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: I've made your LINQ code more idiomatic, I hope you don't mind. I like this solution however it doesn't work for 0 values.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first [Microsoft recommends against this strongly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx).  Some of the stronger words I've heard them use for something they don't enforce on compile:

> Avoid setting a flags enumeration value to zero, unless the value is used to indicate that all flags are cleared. Such a value should be named appropriately as described in the next guideline... Do name the zero value of flags enumerations None. For a flags enumeration, the value must always mean all flags are cleared.

Ok, so why is this happening?  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862614/flags-enumeration-with-multiple-zero-values-problem-textformatflags) I take it's `Enum.ToString` behaving strangely:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

EDIT: I'm able to reproduce your results, but I can't find any more documentation on why it would start printing out the other 0 values.  I would expect it to print NONE of them.

Can you just right-click->refactor->rename them all the same and then delete the others?  It seems easier and less against what Microsoft recommends.

Comment: This is a legacy enum defined in an assembly I can't change.

Comment: Why are you against reflection?  Any particular reason?  This definitely is doable with that.

Comment: I'm not totally against it, but I'd rather it was only used as a last resort. Plus my code may need to execute in a partial trust environment.

Comment: Code formatting for code only, please. It makes plain text harder to read. (True answer, though.)

Comment: Ah, the '>'.  It looks so much prettier!

Comment: @Nathan, I've tried a bit with reflection and the compiler is just confused as anything.  Although Tim Larson's answer won't work exactly as it is, I think you just need to write a function to manually convert it to what you want it to say.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a slightly more complex enum, such as:

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    Nada = 0,
    Zilch = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Four = 4,
}
```

You could implement a simple method that returns the string value for you, like this:

```
public static string TestEnumToString(TestEnum value)
{
    var result = new List();

    if (value == TestEnum.Zero)
    {
        result.Add("Zero");
    }
    if (value == TestEnum.Nada)
    {
        result.Add("Nada");
    }
    if (value == TestEnum.Zilch)
    {
        result.Add("Zilch");
    }
    if ((value & TestEnum.One) != 0)
    {
        result.Add("One");
    }
    if ((value & TestEnum.Two) != 0)
    {
        result.Add("Two");
    }
    if ((value & TestEnum.Four) != 0)
    {
        result.Add("Four");
    }

    return string.Join(",", result);
}
```

Comment: The example here won't quite work since this is marked as 'flags'.  If I have 0x03 as my value, but only a 0x01 and 0x02 in my enum it's going to throw the AgumentException.

Comment: This solution creates a maintenance burden on future developers. I prefer your other suggestion.